# Tag related to ASLR

Tags: discussion, tags

Yesterday I asked this question([Memory Randomization in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/384092/152971)) on Unix and Linux forum and I found it a little difficult to select the tag for it. Though I used the tags `/stack` and `/memory` but I believe that ASLR should be a tag for itself.

**Justification:**

`/stack` : ASLR(Address Space Layout Randomization) includes but is not only limited to Stack randomization.

`/memory` : I believe that stating `memory` as a tag for such questions is too broad and does not points to the problem appropriately.

PS : It's my first ever question in a Meta section. Pardon me if there's a mistake.

Comment: I don't know enough about this to have an opinion on whether a new tag is needed, so I'm not posting an answer, but note that you have enough rep to create a new tag. If you feel it is necessary, you can just write the new tag in and it will be created.

Comment: @terdon: I might have a enough reputation but I have no idea about when a new tag should be created. As I said that it was just I who felt like the lack for a tag but I might as well be wrong. That's the reason I need advice from more experienced members here. If I could find a few members in favor of creating a tag for ASLR, I'd definitely do it.

Comment: Of course, I just wanted to make sure you were aware that you had the right/ability to do it. As I said, I don't know enough about this subject to have an opinion and asking on Meta is never wrong. I'm sure someone who understands this better will offer an opinion.